# Tag DIV excedendo a largura

Tags: html, css

tenho meu portfólio e tenho alguma `<div>` está `estourando` a largura, porém não encontro.

[Link para o site](http://ffsolucoesweb.com/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**na imagem o overflow**

Comment: Esclareça melhor a sua questão, comece por fornecer o código em questão e não apenas a "visualização"

Comment: então, a questão é essa, não sei em que parte do código está o errado, obrigado

Comment: Certo, de qualquer forma se não poder fornecer o código tente fornecer umas imagens explicado o sucedido..

Comment: @RebeloX editei a pergunta com a imagem

Comment: Olá Furlan. Notamos que você tem várias perguntas neste estilo, e você já deve ter percebido que o destino delas é serem fechadas, e talvez futuramente excluídas. Isso porque o objetivo do site é que as perguntas possam ajudar mais gente, então é importante criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve). Também aconselho fortemente esta discussão no meta: [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O div que está "estourando" a width está localizado na linha 473(basicamente é o div que introduz a informação do facebook).
Adicione:

```
style="width:auto;"
```

No Div em causa e o problema deverá ficar resolvido.
Caso não fique, utilize a funcionalidade 3D oferecida pelo firefox e procure pelo elemento que está a sair da resolução do display.

Comment: Para além disso, reparei que o website utiliza bootstrap, então este deveria respeitar a [_Grid_](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) do mesmo, ou seja, para além de incluir o _.col-md-_ deveria utilizar-se o _.col-sm-_ e o _.col-xs-_